Wanted my python application to run in windowsXp but there is problem on installing pandas for it. Its not getting installed (Py version 3.4.4)
I wanted my python application to run in windowsXp  but the problem I noted is it supports 3.4.x versions of python so anyway I downgraded it to 3.4.4 but now I'm facing another problem on installing pandas for it. Its not getting installed at all
whenever I install it by pip install pandas all I see is that Collecting pandas and nothing else than that and later if I see the packages installed using pip list I only see pip(7.1.2) and setuptools(18.2) nothing else...
I tried installing different packages using pip install I expected it to install it as usual but rather I see it gets terminated or stopped right just after stating collecting particular package and gets terminated. No packages were installed

Try installing a version that is compatible with python 3.4: pip install pandas==0.21.0
